# Filtering for "\\%" in SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to query some information from an SQL database. The pattern I am trying to match looks like "\%" - so I want a backslash, followed by any string.

I have the following setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test(id, integer, name varchar(100));
INSERT INTO Test(id, name) values (1, "A\\");
INSERT INTO Test(id, name) values (1, "A\\B");
```

These are the results for different queries:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM Test WHERE name LIKE "A%"; -> 2
SELECT count(*) FROM Test WHERE name LIKE "A\\"; -> 1
SELECT count(*) FROM Test WHERE name LIKE "A\\%"; -> 0
SELECT count(*) FROM Test WHERE name LIKE "A\%"; -> 0
```

Especially given the result of the second query, I would expect `A\\%` to give me both entries, but I get zero. `A\%` does not work either, but that is actually what I would expect as `%` gets escaped in this query.

Is there any way to formulate a statement ending with "\%"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character in LIKE patterns. *And* it is an escape character in MySQL/MariaDB strings. In `'A\%'` it escapes the `%`, which means this ends up matching a literal percent sign.

To end up with the pattern *"`'A'` followed by `'\'`, followed by anything"*, we need to double-escape:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE name LIKE 'A\\\\%'
```

One level of escaping is taken away when SQL parses your query, leaving `'A\\%'`, and the second level is taken away when LIKE interprets the pattern, leaving `'A\%'`, but now with a literal backslash.

It's more manageable to use a different escape character for the LIKE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE name LIKE "A\%" ESCAPE '|';
```

Also see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/#syntax

---

Note that this also works:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE name LIKE 'A\\\%'
```

because when the query is parsed, `'\\'` is unescaped into `'\'`, while `'\%'` is not a valid escape sequence, it cannot be unescaped and stays `'\%'`. The string `LIKE` gets to see ends up being the same as with `'A\\\\%`.

Personally, I consider this unclean escaping. It works, but only by reliance on a parser quirk. This also applies to `'A\%'`, which *should* be written as `'A\\%'`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If this answers solves your issue, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.